# Using custom tag to reference ReactJS components inside ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-component

I have a `ReactJS` basic project which is working fine with the following two files (among others):

**Header.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = () => (
    <div>THIS IS A HEADER</div>
)

export default Header
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Header from './Header'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    Hello World! This is the content.
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

**What I want to know is:**

How can I reference the `Header` component with a custom tag, for example: `<comp-header />` instead of: `<Header />`. Something like below:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Header from './Header'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <comp-header />
                <div>
                    Hello World! This is the content.
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply

```
import CompHeader from './Header'
```

and use  normally.

I don't think you can use a dash in JSX and JSX elements that are non native elements need to be capitalized.